# PHP узнать забитость оперативной памяти

Tags: php, linux

Стоит веб-сервер с linux. Как выдать на странице сколько осталось свободной оперативной памяти. Причем реальной оперативной памяти, не включая всякую виртуальную.

Comment: а Вам не нужно знать "количество реальной памяти" - это знание Вам ничего не даст. К примеру, свобдно 100 мб памяти и что это дает? а ничего. Если другому процессу понадобится память, то система сама выгрузит немного памяти другого процесса в своп (а может и даже этого самого) и память "появится". 

Почитайте это - http://www.rootfront.com/article/9528441/2013-10-04/kak-izmerit-ispolzovanija-pamjati-v-linux

Answer (score 1):

Может быть вам поможет функция
[memory_get_usage](https://www.php.net/memory_get_usage)

Answer (score 0):

как уже было ранее

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455379/get-server-ram-with-php

код - копируй и работает

```
  $fh = fopen('/proc/meminfo','r');
  $mem = 0;
  while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    $pieces = array();
    if (preg_match('/^MemFree:\s+(\d+)\skB$/', $line, $pieces)) {
      $mem = $pieces[1];
      break;
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);

  echo "$mem kB RAM свободно";
```

так-же, в ссылке выше - есть примеры других парсеров!

Answer (score -1):

запустите /usr/bin/free и распарсите ))

Comment: Это да только показывает мне ерунду. показывает ~ 350 мб занято из 384,это бред. я еще запускаю аудио плеер и wget и работает также только теперь 100% занято, но тот же htop показывает что занято ~120 мб это уже больше похоже на правду.

Comment: может cat /proc/meminfo